# PHP variables won't work after dropdown declaration

Tags: php, variables

I've been trying to figure out why my php variables aren't working after the declaration of a dropdown. I've narrowed it down to the dropdown after echoing the variable on all the lines leading up to the declaration, and I found that the variable stops echoing straight after the `echo "<select id ='fav' name='fav'>";` Why is this happening? and how can it be fixed?

```
<?php
$fruit= $_POST['fruit'];
echo $fruit;
echo "<table>";
echo $fruit;
echo "<tr>Favourite Fruit:";
echo $fruit;
echo "<select id ='fav' name='fav'>";
echo $fruit; //this doesn't echo
echo "<option value='Banana'>Banana</option>";
echo "<option value='Strawberry'>Strawberry</option>";
echo "<option value='No Preference'>No Preference</option>";
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: Did you look at the source code?

Comment: @Gumbo sorry I don't understand are you saying if I checked where the variable comes from?

Comment: Actually `$fruit` holds what ?

Comment: I meant, did you look at the source code of the generated HTML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this, if you put something inside

```
<select></select>
```

you have to use

```
<option></option>
```

or you can do it like,

```
  echo $fruit; //this doesn't echo
  echo "<select id ='fav' name='fav'>";
```

but not like,

```
 echo "<select id ='fav' name='fav'>";
 echo $fruit; //this doesn't echo
```

full code will be

```
<?php
$fruit= $_POST['fruit'];
echo $fruit;
echo "<table>";
echo $fruit;
echo "<tr>Favourite Fruit:";
echo $fruit;
echo "<select id ='fav' name='fav'>";
echo '<option value="';
echo $fruit . '">';
echo $fruit;
echo '</option>';
echo '</select>';
.........................
.........................
.........................
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't print any value directly. Try this will work for you.

```
<?php
                        $fruit= $_POST['fruit'];
                        echo $fruit;
                        echo "<table>";
                        echo $fruit;
                        echo "<tr>Favourite Fruit:";
                        echo $fruit;
                        echo "<select id ='fav' name='fav'>";
                        echo "<option value='".$fruit."'>".$fruit."</option>";
                        .........................
                        .........................
                        echo "<option value='No Preference'>No Preference</option>";
                        </select>
                        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the HTML that was generated using your browser's "view source" option, you will probably see that the echo worked fine. The reason you can't see it is that you are trying to put text inside a `<select>` but not inside any `<option>`, so there is nowhere for it to appear on the screen. This has nothing to do with it being a PHP variable.

Comment: The problem is I also have an SQL query in the dropdown and it isn't being set to the variable? so can SQL queries be set inside a dropdown box? or is that also a problem?

Comment: PHP doesn't know whether it's inside a dropdown, so no, that problem is unrelated. However, the approach you are taking to debugging it won't work, because you can't use `echo` there and expect it to show on the screen.

Comment: Hmm fair enough, I understand that now, I'll keep debugging and see where the issue is. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because you forgot close the select tag.close select tag :

```
            <?php
            $fruit= $_POST['fruit'];
            echo $fruit;
            echo "<table>";
            echo $fruit;
            echo "<tr>Favourite Fruit:";
            echo $fruit;
            echo "<select id ='fav' name='fav'></select>";
            echo $fruit; 
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this, You can not call `$fruit` without any `option` tag.

```
$fruit= $_POST['fruit'];
echo "<select id ='fav' name='fav'>";
echo '<option value="';
echo $fruit . '">';
echo $fruit;
echo '</option>';
echo '</select>';
.........................
```